# msal issue: Unexpected token < in angular 5 application

Tags: azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I have been trying to fix this issue since days, any help will be appreciated.
I am trying to import msal(v0.2.0) in angular 5 application. the way I am doing is:

```
import '../../../../../node_modules/msal/dist/msal'
/// <reference path="../../../../../node_modules/msal/dist/msal"/>
import * as Msal from 'msal'
```

So whenever I run my application and try to browse it I get:

> localhost/:64 SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>       at evaluate (http://localhost:5555/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1533829762220:2802:16)
>       at http://localhost:5555/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1533829762220:3607:23
>       at dynamicExecute (http://localhost:5555/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1533829762220:1138:28)
>       at doEvaluate (http://localhost:5555/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1533829762220:1085:15)
>       at ensureEvaluate (http://localhost:5555/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1533829762220:993:15)
>       at http://localhost:5555/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1533829762220:1011:22
>       at Object.eval (http://localhost:5555/app/shared/auth/auth.service.js:54:1)
>       at eval (http://localhost:5555/app/shared/auth/auth.service.js:337:4)
>       at eval (http://localhost:5555/app/shared/auth/auth.service.js:338:3)

Is there anyway around this ?
Is this the right way of importing msal in angular 5 application?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by adding msal to project.config.ts file.

{ name: 'msal', path: 'node_modules/msal/dist/msal.js' }